# Is this passing a Ruby block into itself?

Tags: ruby

Learning Ruby and came across this example in a tutorial

```
x = 10  
5.times do |x|  
  puts "x inside the block: #{x}"  
end  

puts "x outside the block: #{x}"
```

It outputs the following

```
x inside the block: 0
x inside the block: 1
x inside the block: 2
x inside the block: 3
x inside the block: 4
x outside the block: 10
```

How does x increment inside the block?  This must be an incredibly simple problem.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times

Answer (score 0):

`5.times` iterates the block followed 5 times taking values from 0 to 4. Use of x in the loop is local to the block. After the loop is executed x has its original value i.e. 10.

Comment: I understood the scoping part that the code was meant to illustrate.  I didn't get where the values where coming from, and the link to ruby-doc above explained it.